# Why is ld.so a shared object?

Tags: linux, loading, ld, elf

I'm currently writing a dynamic linker and I there is something bugging me.
Why is ld.so (my system's dynamic linker) a shared object ?
Why can't it just be a static executable (ET_EXEC) ?

I tried looking for answer in the linux kernel's binfmt_elf.c but to my understanding it clearly shows that your ELF interpreter could be a static executable.

EDIT:I think my thinking sums up to: Can a dynamic linker be a simple ELF executable (ET_EXEC) ?

[binfmt_elf.c.559](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/binfmt_elf.c#L559):

```
/* First of all, some simple consistency checks */
    if (interp_elf_ex->e_type != ET_EXEC &&
        interp_elf_ex->e_type != ET_DYN)
        goto out;
```

PS: I hope this is the right place, I don't know if I'm supposed to put it here or on Unix stack exchange.
I'm also sorry if my question is stupid but not having an answer to this is driving me crazy.

Comment: Philosophy of design choices?  The she-bang mechanism has an executable interpreting the file.  Are you asking why doesn't the loader act likewise?  I guess it might be a question of economy of processes accountability...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can a dynamic linker be a simple ELF executable (ET_EXEC) ?

Yes, it can.

However, an `ET_EXEC` *must* be loaded at the address it was linked at, and that address may conflict with the address at which `a.out` itself is linked. If such conflict happens, the kernel will either kill the process before it even starts, or it will `mmap` `a.out` "on top of" `ld.so`, and the resulting binary will crash.

You can move `ld.so` out of the way of usual `a.out` link address, but someone can always link `a.out` at un-usual address.

If instead you link `ld.so` as `ET_DYN`, with load address of zero, then none of the above problems could happen.